# How do I open up the transaction dialog popup in Ardor Ignis via the URL parameters when the wallet gui loads in the browser?

Tags: wallet, ardor, ignis, ardor-asset-exchange

I'm able to get to open up the wallet gui via the browser and go straight to the asset page, but how do I open up a transaction popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to open up popups using just the URL, because it's not built inside the codebase.

The only reason you were able to go to a specific page was that there's a loader function for that page.

For instance, `loadAssetFromURL()` for the asset page in `ardor/html/www/js/nrs.assetexchange.js`